# static vs dynamic heterogeneous collection in rust

Tags: rust, polymorphism, traits

I'm brand new to rust so all the lifetimes are probably wrong, please ignore.
Assume that the objects are stored somewhere separate.
Also that the structs, traits and impls have been filled in with useful stuff.
And finally the ordering of the lists doesn't matter.

Fully dynamic version:

```rust
trait Shape {}
struct Sphere {}
struct Triangle {}
impl Shape for Sphere{}
impl Shape for Triangle {}

trait Material {}
struct Diffuse {}
struct Glossy {}
impl Material for Diffuse {}
impl Material for Glossy {}

trait Object {}

struct PrimitiveObject<'a> {
    shape: &'a dyn Shape,
    material: &'a dyn Material,
    position: [f32; 3]
}
struct InstancedObject<'a> {
    shape: &'a dyn Shape,
    material: &'a dyn Material,
    positions: Vec<[f32; 3]>
}
impl<'a> Object for PrimitiveObject<'a> {}
impl<'a> Object for InstancedObject<'a> {}

struct Scene<'a> {
    objects: Vec<&'a dyn Object>
}
```

Slightly more static version

```
struct Scene<'a> {
    objects_PrimitiveObject: Vec<&'a PrimitiveObject<'a>>,
    objects_InstancedObject: Vec<&'a InstancedObject<'a>>
}
```

Fully static version

```rust
struct PrimitiveObject<'a, Shape: Shape_, Material: Material_> {
    shape: &'a Shape_,
    material: &'a Material_,
    position: [f32; 3]
}
struct InstancedObject<'a, Shape: Shape_, Material: Material_> {
    shape: &'a Shape_,
    material: &'a Material_,
    positions: Vec<[f32; 3]>
}
impl<'a, Shape: Shape_, Material: Material_> Object for PrimitiveObject<'a, Shape_, Material_> {}
impl<'a, Shape: Shape_, Material: Material_>  Object for InstancedObject<'a, Shape_, Material_> {}

struct Scene<'a> {
    objects_PrimitiveObject_Sphere_Diffuse: Vec<&'a PrimitiveObject<'a, Sphere, Diffuse>>,
    objects_PrimitiveObject_Sphere_Glossy: Vec<&'a PrimitiveObject<'a, Sphere, Glossy>>,
    objects_PrimitiveObject_Triangle_Diffuse: Vec<&'a PrimitiveObject<'a, Triangle, Diffuse>>,
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to make the static versions not by hand, but using macros?

While the static version has exponential growth in the number of type parameters, it seems like it could be faster than dynamic by allowing inlining where it helps. A bunch of empty vectors doesn't seem like a huge cost.

I guess enums are also in the running, but they seem to have a space disadvantage.

Comment: This seems like a bit of an XY problem. Is there a reason why you want to use types instead of enums?

Comment: sizeof(enum) = max(sizeof(member)) + sizeof(tag) so it seems terribly space inefficient

Comment: It's only terribly inefficient if exactly one of your members is significantly larger than the others, but it is always more efficient in in terms of not having an extra layer of indirection.

Comment: And in case one of the members is significantly larger, you could consider boxing just that member.

Comment: Looping over a list of enums is horrible for branch prediction. It's similar to dynamic dispatch, no? The extra layer of indirection is still there in the tag

Comment: Dynamic dispatch is worse because it kills cache locality for both instructions and data.